# enviar datos de form a otra vista

Tags: php, html

Hols estoy trabajando con un servidor remoto y intento hacer un formulario en una vista que al apretar enviar me lleve a otra vista donde voy a ver los datos de ese usuario, datos que ingreso y que hay en la ase de datos, este es mi formulario pero al enviarlo a la vista me dice error 404 estoy trabajando con html y php

```
<form action="validar.php" method="post">
<h2>Formulario</h2>
<input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Email" name="email">
<input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
```

Comment: Si te dice 404 es por qué la ruta del archivo al que apuntas está incorrecta y por tanto no lo encuentra

Comment: La url está mal, no sé si validar.php está dentro de una carpeta y si es así tu URL tendría que ser así carpeta/validar.php